# replace a column given the position of a negative number of another vector in R?

Tags: r, matrix, vector

```
A<-matrix(c(1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1),nrow=3,ncol=3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    1    1
[3,]    1    2    1

B<-c(1,2,-1)
```

For example I want to replace all of the third column with all NA's because the third element in B is negative.
I was thinking something like this

```
NegNum<-length(B[B<0])
A[,tail(NegNum)]<-NA
```

The negative numbers are always in the last n positions of B so i tried to use tail but im not sure how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest indexing based on `B`:

```
#Matrix 1
A<-matrix(c(1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1),nrow=3,ncol=3)
#Vector
B<-c(1,2,-1)
#Solution
A[,which(B<0)]<-NA
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1   NA
[2,]    2    1   NA
[3,]    1    2   NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another base R option

```
A %*% diag(replace(B, B < 0, NA))
```

or

```
replace(A,cbind(seq(nrow(A)),rep(which(B<0),nrow(A))),NA)
```

which gives

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1   NA
[2,]    2    1   NA
[3,]    1    2   NA
```